# Can you quickly find the inverse Fourier Transform using the duality property?

Tags: fourier-transform

Cheers, in an exercise of mine I reach the point that I have to find the $F^{-1}\{Λ(ω)\}$ (where $Λ(ω)$ is the triangle function, with $1-|ω|$ for $|ω| \leq 1 $ and 0 elsewhere. Using the duality property, I know that I will have to end up with a $sinc$ function, and I also that for $x(t) = Atri(\frac{t}{T})$ we get the transform $X(ω) = F\{x(t)\} = \frac{\sin^2(πf)}{(πf)^2}$. Is there a quick way to find the result of $\frac{1}{2π}\frac{sinc^2(\frac{t}{2})}{(t/2)^2}$ without having to use the definition with the integral? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You know a Fourier transform pair

$$x(t)\Longleftrightarrow X(\omega)\tag{1}$$

with

$$\mathcal{F}\big\{x(t)\big\}=X(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\tag{2}$$

and

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{X(\omega)\big\}=x(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(\omega)e^{j\omega t}d\omega\tag{3}$$

Now you want to find the inverse Fourier transform of $x(\omega)$:

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{x(\omega)\big\}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\omega)e^{j\omega t}d\omega\tag{4}$$

Comparing $(4)$ with $(2)$ you can see that

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{x(\omega)\big\}=\frac{1}{2\pi}X(-t)\tag{5}$$

So from

$$\mathcal{F}\big\{x(t)\big\}=X(\omega)\tag{6}$$

it follows that

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{x(\omega)\big\}=\frac{1}{2\pi}X(-t)\tag{7}$$

If you use the unitary definition of the Fourier transform with frequency variable $f=\omega/2\pi$ then you can get rid of the factor $1/2\pi$ in the duality formula $(7)$.

Answer (score 0):

$ sinc^2(Wt)\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{W}tri(\frac{f}{W})$ is a Fourier transform pair. Changing angular frequency from $tri(\omega)$ function to $tri(2\pi f)$ then $\frac{1}{W}=2\pi$ and $W=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ . So $2\pi \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{tri(2\pi f)\big\}= sinc^2(\frac{t}{2 \pi})$ now divide both sides with $2\pi$ to get $ \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{tri(2\pi f)\big\}= \frac{1}{2\pi}sinc^2(\frac{t}{2 \pi})$.